# Ubuntu 20.04 zsys snapshot management unclear

Tags: 20.04, zfs

I have been looking for any useful documentation for zsys.

1. In particular. I'd like to know if there is a policy for removing old snapshots and if there is a way to tweak it.
2. I'd like to know if there is a way to add additional zpools to zsys, for example lxd containers, where each has its own snapshot
   managed.

Comment: This article has information regarding the policy for removing snapshots: https://didrocks.fr/2020/06/04/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20.04-lts-zsys-state-collection/